# How to SUM cells from DataTables when checked?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, datatables, sum

I want to SUM values from cells when I check then. Like:

[image]

I´ve found how on DataTables website but it is not quite like I need.
Will be a lot of data on this table, and I want to SUM their values when the checkbox is checked, the save the total on a variable to pass to a controller.

P.S.: I forgot to say that I am using VueJS. Let´s see some code.

```
@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.16/af-2.2.2/b-1.5.1/b-colvis-1.5.1/b-flash-1.5.1/b-html5-1.5.1/b-print-1.5.1/cr-1.4.1/fh-3.1.3/kt-2.3.2/rg-1.0.2/rr-1.2.3/sl-1.2.5/datatables.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/moment-with-locales.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        isLoading: false,
        cliente: '{{ $contemplado->id }}',
        checked : false,
        nrocpfCnpj: "{!! $contemplado->cpfCnpj !!}",
        porte: '{!! $contemplado->porte !!}',
        natureza_juridica: '{!! $contemplado->natureza_juridica !!}',
        idERP: '{!! $contrato->idERP !!}',
        originalSegmento: '{!! $contrato->originalSegmento !!}',
        novoSegmento: '{!! $contrato->novoSegmento !!}',
        isLoading: false,
        grupo: '{!! $contrato->grupo !!}',
        cota: '{!! $contrato->cota !!}',
    },

    mounted() {

        const vm = this
        var tabela = $('#example').dataTable({
            "language": {
                'url': '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Portuguese-Brasil.json'
            },
            'scrollX': true,
            'scrollY': false,
            'autoWidth': true,
            responsive: true,
            processing: true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "montaTabelaMultiCota",
                "data": {
                    "nrocpfCnpj": vm.nrocpfCnpj
                }
            },
            columns: [
                { data: null,
                    fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        $(nTd).html("<div class='form-check'><input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' name='cota"+oData['NUMERO-COTA']+"' value='"+oData['VALOR-BEM']+"'></div>")
                    }
                },
                { data: 'CODIGO-GRUPO'},
                { data: 'NUMERO-COTA',
                    fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        $(nTd).html(oData['NUMERO-COTA'])
                    }
                },
                { data: 'DESCRICAO-BEM'},
                { data: 'VALOR-BEM',
                    fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        $(nTd).html("R$ "+oData['VALOR-BEM']+",00")
                    }
                    },
                { data: 'NUMERO-CONTRATO'},
                { data: 'DATA-CONTEMPLACAO',
                        fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        moment.locale('pt-br');
                        var data = oData['DATA-CONTEMPLACAO'];
                        let criado = moment(data, 'YYYYMMDD').fromNow();
                            $(nTd).html(criado);
                    }
                },
                { data: 'DATA-ENTREGA',
                        fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        moment.locale('pt-br');
                        var data = oData['DATA-ENTREGA'];
                        let criado = moment(data, 'YYYYMMDD').fromNow();
                            $(nTd).html(criado);
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        // Adds the values and updates the readonly input.
        function updateTotal(){
            $('input#total').val($('input.selected:checked').toArray().reduce(function(last, current){
                return last + parseInt($(current).attr('data-value'));
            }, 0));
        }
        // init the total value and bind updateTotal function to the change event on the checkboxes.
        function dt_init(){
            updateTotal();
            $('.selected').off('change').on('change', function(e) {
                updateTotal();
            });
        }

        var dt = $('#dt_container').DataTable({
            // Add the checkboxes and set the values in a data-* attribute for later
            rowCallback: function(row, data){
                let value = parseInt($('td:eq(4)', row).html().substring(3))
                // $('td:eq(4)', row).html()  : 'R$ 12975.00'
                // 'R$ 12975.00'.substring(3) : '12975.00'
                // parseInt('12975.00')       : 12975
                $('td:eq(0)', row).html(`<input class="selected" type="checkbox" data-value=${value}>`)
            },
            // If you need to redraw your table (sort, search, page), then you need to redo some things, that's why dt_init is called upon every time.
            initComplete: function(settings, json, param){
                // show the footer after the DataTable is done
                $(dt.table().footer()).css('display', '');
                dt_init();
            },
            drawCallback: function(settings){
                dt_init();
            }
        });
    },
});

</script>
@endsection
```

Any helps?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a footer in your datatable. Just make it initially invisible and add some boilerplate to show some results.

```html
<table id="dt_container">
    <tfoot style="display: none;">
        <tr>
            <th>Total:</th>
            <th><input id="total" type="text" name="total" value="" readonly></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Next, in the javascript init the DataTable but add some callbacks

```js
// Adds the values and updates the readonly input.
function updateTotal(){
    $('input#total').val($('input.selected:checked').toArray().reduce(function(last, current){
        return last + parseInt($(current).attr('data-value'));
    }, 0);
}
// init the total value and bind updateTotal function to the change event on the checkboxes.
function dt_init(){
    updateTotal();

    $('.selected').off('change').on('change', function(e){
        updateTotal();
    });
}

var dt = $('#dt_container').DataTable({
    // Add the checkboxes and set the values in a data-* attribute for later
    rowCallback: function(row, data){
        let value = parseInt($('td:eq(4)', row).html().substring(3))
        // $('td:eq(4)', row).html()  : 'R$ 12975.00'
        // 'R$ 12975.00'.substring(3) : '12975.00'
        // parseInt('12975.00')       : 12975
        $('td:eq(0)', row).html(`<input class="selected" type="checkbox" data-value=${value}>`)
    },
    // If you need to redraw your table (sort, search, page), then you need to redo some things, that's why dt_init is called upon every time.
    initComplete: function(settings, json, param){
        // show the footer after the DataTable is done
        $(dt.table().footer()).css('display', '');
        dt_init();
    },
    drawCallback: function(settings){
        dt_init();
    }
});
```

Comment: Dear @IGP, besides of a typo at $.('.selected), your script just doesn´t work at all. 
I´ve edited my question adding your code. What I missed?

Comment: Rereading your updated question, I'm afraid my code is meant for JQuery and not Vue.

Comment: OK, I´ll try to convert it to VueJS. Thanks!